# Cron Job doesn't trigger with TimeZone

Tags: go, cron

I've been doing some test with cron jobs with timezones.
My goal is to setup 1 cron job per timezone so it can be run independently of the server location.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/robfig/cron"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

func helloWorld() {
  fmt.Println("hello world")
}

func main() {
    s, err1 := cron.Parse("26 15 * * *")
    fmt.Println(err1)
    l, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Tokyo")
    fmt.Println(err)
    c := cron.NewWithLocation(l)
    c.Schedule(s, cron.FuncJob(helloWorld))
    c.Start()

    sig := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(sig, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)
    <-sig
}
```

Here i'm just trying to make a test. I expect to see helloWorld at 15:26 Tokyo time. ( 3:26PM )

The sig snippet is something i've found on stack overflow for testing purposes so that the program doesn't close before the cron job has time to run.

I'm always setting up the time 1 or 2 minutes ahead and it's never working.
any idea why ?

Comment: If you're setting it 1-2 min ahead, the problem is most likely that when you change the timezone, you're adjusting it to a time in the past, or distant future.

Comment: it's in the timezone i'm living in, should that still be a problem ? i'm basically testing it vs my computer clock , 2 min ahead. I'm just manually imputing the Asia/Tokyo timezone for testing purpose but i shouldn't need it since that's where i live ( so that's my computer clock ).

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's the timezone you live in. When you adjust "15:26" to any other time zone, it's no longer "15:26", so won't run when you expect.

Comment: so it's 15:26 adjusted , not 15:26 at defined timezone ?!  How should i proceed to make it run at 15:26  for location "Asia/Tokyo" ? I need to schedule things at different time zones. 16h30 Tokyo time , 10AM  London time , etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I was an error of the cron formula `"26 15 * * *"`  should have been `"00 26 15 * *"`